# Jumble Word Game using jQuery ui-sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying out a jumble word game using jQuery ui-sortable where users can try swapping the elements and submit their answer. Here, the user will be given two opportunities. In case if the user fails in his first submission of answer, he will be given another chance by freezing the correct characters which means not allowing to move the correct characters. I want only the wrong characters to be moved or exchanged between the other wrong characters. I tried the below code

```
$("#word_"+i).sortable({
                axis: 'x',
                items: 'label:not(.correctText)',
                cancel: '.correctText',
                scrollSensitivity: 1,
                tolerance: "pointer" ,
                start: function(){
                    $(this).find("label:not(.ls)").each(function () {
                        $(this).data("fixedIndex", $(this).index());
                    });
                },
                change: function(){
                 $(this).find("label:not(.ls)").each(function () {                       
                    attrID = $(this).closest(".ui-sortable").attr("id");                        
                    if($(this).data("fixedIndex")!=0)
                    {
                      $(this).detach().insertAfter($("#"+attrID+" label:eq(" + ($(this).data("fixedIndex")-1) + ")"));                          
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      $(this).detach().insertBefore($("#"+attrID+" label:eq(" + ($(this).data("fixedIndex")) + ")"));
                    }
                  }); 
                }
            });
           $("#word_"+i+" label.correctText").disableSelection();          
}
```

I am able to freeze correct elements by using the above logic but not for consecutive correct characters, if i move second and third letters to its correct position and submit. Its getting freezed but when i try to move the first wrong element to somewhere right, then i am into trouble. It moves the correct characters to wrong position.

Comment: please setup a jsfiddle so that we have a working code to play with :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the interest mandeep.. please find the updated and latest js fiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/JZ74V/6/

To start, move second, third and may be the fourth letter to its correct place.. Rest in wrong position, then submit.. Correct letters will change to green and be freezed, now try moving first letter to its right or in some position.. You will understand my problem..

Comment: @HimanthKumar I'm unable to reproduce/understand the issue. it seems to be working fine for me. Can you minimize the fiddle with a single word, update the question with the link to fiddle and provide step by step instructions to reproduce the issue..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your response Tilwin Joy, i actually fixed it myself.. Updated code set is at

jsfiddle.net/JZ74V/32/

This fiddle set could help you understand my requirement, may you make use of it if required.